# Visual Studio 2013 hangs on start of installation in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, visual-studio-2013

I'm having a problem installing VS 2013 Ultimate Edition.

I'm using the .iso installer, however I get the same problem with the web installer.

The installer starts and it just hangs there, no CPU activity, no memory consumption, no error messages, nothing.

My OS is a Windows 10, 64 bit, upgraded from Windows 8.

In my `%temp%` folder there are `.log` files, and in all of them these are the last lines:

> [160C:0618][2015-10-25T22:55:37]e000: MUX:  **ERROR: Customized cultures cannot be passed by LCID, only by name.**
>   [160C:0618][2015-10-25T22:55:37]e000: MUX:  Stack:    at
>      System.Globalization.CompareInfo.GetCompareInfoWithPrefixedLcid(Int32 cultureKey, Int32 prefix)
>      at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.get_CompareInfo()
>      at System.String.StartsWith(String value, Boolean ignoreCase, CultureInfo culture)
>      at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.SelectableItemViewModel.GetLocText(String text)
>      at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.SelectableItemViewModel.get_Description()
>      at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.CustomizationViewModel.InitializeViewModel()
>      at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.CustomizationViewModel..ctor(ViewModelBase
>   viewModel)
>      at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ViewModelBase.get_CustomizationViewModel()
>      at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ViewModelBase.DetectComplete(Object sender, DetectCompleteEventArgs e)
>      at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ViewModelCommonUi.DetectComplete(Object sender, DetectCompleteEventArgs e)
>
> [160C:0618][2015-10-25T22:55:37]e000: MUX:  **ERROR: Customized cultures cannot be passed by LCID, only by name.**
>   [160C:0618][2015-10-25T22:55:37]e000: MUX:  Stack:    at
>      System.Globalization.CompareInfo.GetCompareInfoWithPrefixedLcid(Int32 cultureKey, Int32 prefix)
>      at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.get_CompareInfo()
>      at System.String.StartsWith(String value, Boolean ignoreCase, CultureInfo culture)
>      at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.SelectableItemViewModel.GetLocText(String text)
>      at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.SelectableItemViewModel.get_Description()
>      at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.CustomizationViewModel.InitializeViewModel()
>      at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.CustomizationViewModel..ctor(ViewModelBase viewModel)
>      at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ViewModelBase.get_CustomizationViewModel()
>      at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ViewModelBase.DetectComplete(Object sender, DetectCompleteEventArgs e)
>      at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ViewModelCommonUi.DetectComplete(Object sender, DetectCompleteEventArgs e)
>      at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.ViewModelInteractive.DetectComplete(Object sender, DetectCompleteEventArgs e)
>   [160C:0618][2015-10-25T22:55:37]i199: **Detect complete, result: 0x0**

Any kind of help / hint, whatever, would be kindly appreciated.

Best regards,
Stefan.

Comment: I remember someone else having issues with their Visual Studio 2013 install, he ended up just downloading Visual Studio 2015 (which is free). Is there any reason for you to stay on 2013?

Comment: VS can take a long time to install/uninstall; how long did you let it sit for before cancelling?

Comment: do you use the original VS2013 RTM iso? If yes, try an ISO which includes the Update 5.

Comment: @Insane Unfortunately, for this particular project I am limited to 2013. Switching to another IDE is a nice workaround in general but I would still be interested to find out what the problem / solution is for cases like mine.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I know it usually takes a long time, but it usually moves beyond the splash screen. In this case it was frozen at the splash screen, no progress bar no nothing, for about an hour.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes, I am using the installer with the Update 5

Comment: which language does your Windows have? change it to en-US and after setup change back to ru-ru

Comment: @magicandre1981 The language was set to en-US. There was another setting, for the non-Unicode programs, which was set to Russian, I changed that also to en-US, but the result was the same.

Comment: ask this in the Microsoft VS setup forum (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/threads) and provide the setup logs: http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=8967043

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to change the region of the OS.
From the MSDN [forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b0dfdc42-18b8-4820-9f5f-fda106217b1b/visual-studio-2013-hangs-on-start-of-installation-in-windows-10?forum=vssetup):

> Change the region settings of the operation system to a format whose LCID does not equal 4096. The format can be changed in *Control Panel > Region > Formats*.

The previous format was *English (Europe)*, and I changed it to *English (UK)*.